# jq command executes differently - one successfully and the other is not

Tags: jq, aws-cli

I am running this command:

```
{{ aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region ca-central-1 | jq '.AvailabilityZones[]|(.ZoneName)}}'
```

on 2 identical MacOs and one Amazon Linux.

The MacOs subject to this question is showing this error :

> parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 18

However, the Amazon and the Other MacOS are showing the correct output

[image]

Please help me! This is driving me crazy

Comment: Could you show at least some of the output of the AWS command as produced in the Mac environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates that the input piped to `jq` wasn't valid JSON. Since this input comes directly from the output of the `aws ec2 describe-instances` command it looks like it isn't emitting JSON, or it's emitting other text *as well* as JSON.

The fastest way to diagnose this is going to be for you to find out what text the `aws` command is emitting.

One possible cause could be that you have it configured via an environment variable (`AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT`) or configuration file (e.g. `~/.aws/config`) to output YAML or text or tables. (In fact, I consider this probable. I can reproduce the error message exactly down to the column number if I set it to output YAML.) You could rule this out by [explicitly specifying](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output-format.html#cli-usage-output-format) `--output json`.

Beyond that, I suggest you compare these machines to each other. For example, try this on each machine and see what's different on the odd machine:

```
echo Versions:
aws --version
jq --version

echo Environment:
env | grep '^AWS_'

echo AWS configuration:
aws configure list

echo AWS config file:
cat ~/.aws/config
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Weebe, as you pointed out the default output was YAML, changed it to JSON, and now it's giving the expected results.
Much appreciated the detail and thorough answer!